# COM component doesn't remain accessible in VBScript

Tags: c#, .net, com, vbscript

I have a C# class library project (dll) with a single class, COMTest:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace COMTest
{
    [Guid("45D639E4-FDDE-4b7b-A35F-FC19856DFF24")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Foo
    {
        public Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Constructing Foo");
        }

        private string mName = "FOO";
        public string Name
        {
            get { return mName; }
            set { mName = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

The project is registered for COM interop, and the assembly is COM-visible.  The target framework is .Net 3.5, and the platform target is x86.  The .dll is registered using the 32-bit `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe /codebase COMTest.dll`

I am attempting to access this class from VBScript (again, 32-bit, using `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe test.vbs`), but I appear to be having problems acquiring an instance of `Foo` within the script.  I can use the class; I just can't keep any reference to it.

Here is my script:

```
Wscript.Echo "CreateObject(""ComTest.Foo"").Name Results: " + CreateObject("COMTest.Foo").Name
IF IsEmpty(CreateObject("COMTest.Foo")) THEN Wscript.Echo "CreateObject() is empty" ELSE Wscript.Echo "CreateObject() is NOT empty"

DIM foo : CreateObject("COMTest.Foo")
IF IsEmpty(foo) THEN Wscript.Echo "foo is empty" ELSE Wscript.Echo "foo is NOT empty"
```

And here is the output:

```
Constructing Foo
CreateObject("ComTest.Foo").Name Results: FOO
Constructing Foo
CreateObject() is NOT empty
Constructing Foo
foo is empty
```

As you can see, the `CreateObject()` call succeeds--I'm just unable to keep a reference to the object returned (in `foo`).

I feel like I'm missing something simple.  How do I retain the object returned from `CreateObject()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon you use in line three doesn't actually do anything, it just separates two different statements. Your `Dim foo : CreateObject("COMTest.Foo")` is equivalent to:

```
Dim foo
CreateObject("COMTest.Foo")
```

Which creates the object but doesn't actually set its reference to any variable.  I would write it like this:

```
Dim foo
Set foo = CreateObject("COMTest.Foo")
WScript.Echo foo.Name
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something easy.  Thank you.